# Target the text between the tags?

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

Is there any way to target this line by the text `next »` inside? I know it's a strange request but I searched and couldn't find the answer. I was hoping someone here could help.

```
  <a href="http://google.com">next »</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
 $('a:contains("next »")');
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/PzgnA/

EDIT - to change the text use text()

```
 $('a:contains("next »")').text('New text here');
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/PzgnA/1/

Comment: thanks, sorry for the double question but how would I change the text to something else? Just use `.html`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('A:contains("next »")')
```

You may need to escape the `raquo;` in the selector for it to work in older versions of jQuery.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qH4mK/)